# TinyMce Change Border Color

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-6

I have implemented tinymce like below.

```
function initTinymce(){

tinymce.init({
selector: '#tinymce_textarea',
plugins: 'autolink link code lists media table image textcolor paste directionality wordcount charmap hr pagebreak insertdatetime advlist save autoresize',
font_family_formats:
    "Andale Mono=andale mono,times; Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; Courier New=courier new,courier; Georgia=georgia,palatino; Helvetica=helvetica; Impact=impact,chicago; Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Terminal=terminal,monaco; Times New Roman=times new roman,times; Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva; Verdana=verdana,geneva; Webdings=webdings; Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",

toolbar: [
    {
    name: 'history',
    items: ['undo', 'redo'],
    },
    {
    name: 'formatting',
    items: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'removeformat'],
    },
    {
    name: 'colors',
    items: ['forecolor', 'backcolor'],
    },
    {
    name: 'alignment',
    items: ['alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'alignjustify'],
    },
    {
    name: 'lists',
    items: ['bullist', 'numlist'],
    },
],
toolbar_mode: 'floating',
toolbar_sticky: true,
tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
autocorrect_autocorrect: false,
max_height: 300,
min_height: 300,
    
autoresize_bottom_margin: 10,
save_onsavecallback: () => {
    callNativeApp ();
},
mobile: {
menubar: false
},
branding: false,
statusbar: false,
promotion: false,
init_instance_callback(editor) {
    getWordCount();
},
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on("change", function () {
        callNativeApp(editor);
    });
    editor.on("keyup", function () {
        getWordCount();
        callNativeApp(editor);
        editingBegin();
    });
}
});
```

}

Now I need to change border color of the tinymce container when the user reached the maximum word count. I was able to get the word count using below code.

```
function getWordCount() {
try {
    const count = tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.wordcount.body.getWordCount();
    webkit.messageHandlers.wordCountCallbackHandler.postMessage(count);
} catch(err) {
    console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
}
```

}

But I couldn't able to find a way to change the border color of the tinymce. Could you please help to do this?

Comment: Please provide a codepen or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to give the border color to the text area (where the user can type) in `tinymce`.

The selector of that text area wrapper is `.tox-editor-container`. So in your `getWordCount` function, you can do something like this-

```
function getWordCount() {
  try {
    const count = tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.wordcount.body.getWordCount();
    webkit.messageHandlers.wordCountCallbackHandler.postMessage(count);
    // If reaches max then give a red border else do not
    document.querySelector('.tox-editor-container').style.border = count > YOUR_MAX_WORD_COUNT ? '3px solid red' : '';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
  }
}
```

If you want to exclude the border from the toolbar then you can try the `.tox-sidebar-wrap` selector.

```
document.querySelector('.tox-sidebar-wrap').style.border = count > YOUR_MAX_WORD_COUNT ? '3px solid red' : '';
```